# Triage audit deleted as spam

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, triage

This is the audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7844643

I marked it as "Looks OK". In hindsight, I admit I should have reviewed "Should be improved", as there is a lot to be improved about the question. That was my mistake.

However, I disagree that it should be marked as spam. It appears to be asking a valid (albeit low-quality) question - in fact, the user has asked a series of valid questions.

I received a 2 day ban from review queue, <s>so I don't know what to do with my life anymore</s> which is not that big a deal.

Comment: Are you sure it was deleted as spam, not just deleted for being crap?

Comment: " It's fine to answer your own question, but it's not fine to ask a question just so you can promote your own work. This is spam. –  Bill the Lizard♦ 2 days ago "

Comment: But if it is not spam how on earth does that Look OK? It is overly broad or unclear...

Comment: That is true. However, I have gotten similar flags disputed in the past (e.g. "too broad" on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29654586/for-riot-api-how-to-get-a-champ-kill-stats-right-after-a-game) and I make mistakes occasionally.

Comment: "Disputed flags" mean people just clicking "Looks OK" or "Should be Improved" in the triage queue. Probably in the same queue event you are in. That question you link to in your comment is certainly too broad, but I imagine a bunch of people chose "Should be Improved".

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I will try to disregard disputed flags more in the future.